# Migrate partial svn repository to Mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial, migration, hgsubversion, mercurial-convert

I need migrate a local folder which is a svn checkout to a mercurial repository, but I cannot make a svn checkout anymore (the svn server is gone), and the folder is not the trunk root, is something like

> svnrepourl/trunk/src/folder

In my laptop I just have `folder`, not the full svn trunk, I  tried hg convert but I got this error:

> http://repositoryurl/svn/src/project does not look like a Subversion repository

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working Copy is not repository, obvious.

You have **nothing** to convert, but you can unversion WC of SVN (it haven't history anyway), copy to the proper location inside of existing Mercurial repo, or create new repo inside former-WC `folder`